# flutter height of slider widget?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am confused what the width of the slider widget is: I have a stack and added an align widget that contains a slider.

Code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: OptionsBar(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}



class OptionsBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const OptionsBar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _OptionsBarState createState() => _OptionsBarState();
}

class _OptionsBarState extends State<OptionsBar> {
  double progress = 0.0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Slider(
            value: progress,
            onChanged: (double newValue) => setState(() => progress = newValue),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The code works but places the slider in the middle of the screen. However, if I give the widget that contains the slider a height than the bar remains at the bottom. So, does that mean that a slider takes up the entire height that it can get? Seems a little bit strange or am I getting something wrong?

Comment: Try setting the height property in the Container.

Answer (score 0):

You have set alignment to bottom that's why when you set height of widget it remains on the bottom. Try to set height to the widget that containing slider and change alignment.